# Order of priors in sklearn LinearDiscriminantAnalysis

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm fitting a Linear Discriminant Analysis model using the stock market data (Smarket.csv) from [here](https://github.com/JWarmenhoven/ISLR-python/tree/master/Notebooks/Data). I'm trying to predict `Direction` with columns `Lag1` and `Lag2`. `Direction` has two values: `Up` or `Down`.

Here is my reproducible code and the result:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis

url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JWarmenhoven/ISLR-python/master/Notebooks/Data/Smarket.csv"
Smarket=pd.read_csv(url, usecols=range(1,10), index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

X_train = Smarket[:'2004'][['Lag1', 'Lag2']]
y_train =  Smarket[:'2004']['Direction']


LDA = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
model = LDA.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(model.priors_)
[0.49198397 0.50801603]
```

How do I know which prior value corresponds to which class (`Up` or `Down`)? I looked at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html) but there seems to be nothing.

Can someone explain it to me or point me to a resource that explains this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I cannot find an explicit reference in the documentation (I'm sure there is a general one, somewhere), in such cases the classes are ordered *alphabetically*, ie. in your case it is `['Down', 'Up']`.

You can easily verify that this is consistent with your results here; since the `priors_` attribute is just passed through the `priors` argument, which, according to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html), is just the class proportions as inferred from the training data (when `priors=None`, like here):

```
y_train.value_counts(normalize=True)
```

gives:

```
Up      0.508016
Down    0.491984
Name: Direction, dtype: float64
```

and

```
model.priors_[0] == (y_train.value_counts(normalize=True)['Down']
# True
model.priors_[1] == (y_train.value_counts(normalize=True)['Up']
# True
```